# djagno, rest_framework..TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner in django.
I do not know why this is an error. Please help me. ㅠ^ㅠ

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Following is my code:

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
    content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
    super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


@csrf_exempt
def mood_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        mood = Mood.objects.all()
        serializer = MoodSerializer(mood, many=True)
        return JSONRenderer(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = MoodSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove data parameter in *JSONParser* class. `**kwargs` already exists. You can access to data parameter with `kwargs` as `kwargs['data']` or `kwargs.get('data')` as it is a python dictionary.

Also, change the return  statement as `return JSONParser(data=serializers.errors, status=400)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my problem was that I wrote the JSONResponse incorrectly in the JSONRendere where I need to write